# Setting up nginx to forward to a local domain does not seem to work, unless location is /

Tags: nginx

I'm fiddling with nginx, first time. So I thought, let set up a simple proxy server, should work right? However, I'm stuck at a simple proxy forward. I have set up the following which does work.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8113;
    }
}
```

However, the following does not seep to work:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /subdomain/ {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8113;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone finds this problem, the solution was for Deluge:

proxy_set_header X-Deluge-Base "/deluge/"